# I want to pass a 2d array to the octave function "imregionalmax" from a C++ code

Tags: c++, api, linker, octave

I have written a C++ code where I read a CSV file and store it to a 2D array and then pass it to the octave function **imregionalmax**. But the code is giving segmentation fault(core dumped). Please help me in this matter.Please provide C++ code if possible. I am attaching my code below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <octave/oct.h>
#include <octave/octave.h>
#include <octave/parse.h>
#include <octave/interpreter.h>

#define ROW 100
#define COL 1000

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    std::ifstream f;
    f.open ("Mat30.csv");
    if (! f.is_open()) {    /* validate file open for reading */
        std::cerr << "error: file open failed '" << argv[1] << "'.\n";
        return 1;
    }
    std::string line, val;                  
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> array;

    while (std::getline (f, line)) {        /* read each line */
        std::vector<float> v;                 /* row vector v */
        std::stringstream s (line);         /* stringstream line */
        while (getline (s, val, ','))       /* get each value (',' delimited) */
            v.push_back (std::stof (val));  /* add to row vector */
        array.push_back (v);                /* add row vector to array */


    string_vector argv_octave (2);
    argv_octave(0) = "embedded";
    argv_octave(1) = "-q";
    octave_main (1, argv_octave.c_str_vec (), 2);

    octave_value_list in1 , in2;

    for(octave_idx_type i = 0 ; i < ROW ; i++) {
        for(octave_idx_type j = 0 ; j < COL ; j++)
            in1(j) = octave_value(array[i][j]);
        in2(i) = in1;
    }
    
    // segmentation fault (core dumped) occurs here. Execution is not going further
    octave_value_list out = feval ("imregionalmax", in2, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

I am using ubuntu 18.04 and Octave is installed in my machine
i am running the code by writting the terminal "**mkoctfile --link-stand-alone file_name.cpp -o file_name && ./file_name**"

Comment: I dont have linux  nor octave, but i have checked the documentation and are you sure this line isn't the cause of the error  in2(i) = in1; because in2(i) return octave_value data type and the data type of in1 is octave_value_list

Comment: Also, maybe you need to give `in1` and `in2` a size before putting data into them. I don’t know for sure, the docs have no text in them, but it makes sense in C++. Also, each element in the `octave_value_list` is one input argument to the function. You should make an `octave_value` that is the full array.